# Can Epiphany browser tabs be made more conspicuous?

Tags: epiphany, web-browser

I enjoy the minimalism of Epiphany, though, as a suggestion, it would be useful to allow some implementation/configuration of security features beyond reliance upon Certificates.

My main issue is that I find it difficult to distinguish between the currently active tab and other tabs that are open; the box shadow is, in my opinion, not enough of a differentiator between the current active tab and inactive tabs. Owing to this small issue, I am constantly closing tabs unintentionally. Perhaps, to make another suggestion, a darker shade of Grey would help.

I would post this to the dev. area, but I don't know where it is.

Comment: Not what you asked but consider Vivaldi. It's very customizable. Write your own css and everything.

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS themes Epiphany to match elementary's theme, so there's nothing the Epiphany developers can do about this. Upstream Epiphany looks different and there is more contrast.

You could ask the elementary developers to make theme changes to their GtkNotebook widget.

Comment: Thank you for the information; I shall try to do as you have suggested. I don't believe I am the only one to experience this issue, but it looks like I the first to voice concern.

Comment: Just had a look over Vivaldi. It's a bit too fussy for me. I'm not one to tinker (with browsers). However, the colour scheme, the layout and some of the features make browsing a lot easier. I've gone ahead and installed it; I'll see how I get on with it over the days. Thank you for the suggestion.